# How to save a position in a file while reading it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to save a reference to a character in a file, then go back to it in the future without iterating through the file. For example, I want to save the reference to X in the following file then in the future, immediately jump to it at a later time without iterating through "nfqo fin qoeif ngo gqowe uzoi asdfjis"

```
...
nfqo fin qoeif
ngo gqowe uzoi
asdfjis X kajs
...
```

Then I want to get the character following the marked reference, for example:

```
saved_reference = X
third_char = saved_reference + 3 # should return 'a'
```

Comment: So say that fp.tell() returns 41 (the position of X in the file) and I close the file. Open it again and want to jump to position 41 without iterating/running through 1-40. How would I do that step?

Comment: ```fp.seek(40)``` and then ```fp.read(1)```  to get "X".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ewong has commented. To save the position of the marker in the file as I reading it, character-by-character, I can use `saved_reference = fp.tell()` to get the position/reference of the marker. To later jump to it, I do `fp.seek(saved_reference)`. Lastly, if I want to read the third character after it, I first do `fp.seek(saved_reference+2)`, then do `f.read(1)`.